# How to return a value inside AJAX function to parent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to return true or false to a function depending on the response of an AJAX function inside of it but I'm not sure how should I do it.

```
(function($) {
    $('#example').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit : function(arr, $form, options) {

            var jsonStuff = JSON.stringify({ stuff: 'test' });

            $.post('/echo/json/', { json: jsonStuff }, function(resp) {

                if (resp.stuff !== $('#test').val()) {
                     // Cancel form submittion
                     alert('Need to type "test"');
                     return false; // This doesn't work          
                }

            }, 'json');

        },
        success : function() {
             alert('Form sent!');   
        }
    });   
})(jQuery);​
```

I made a fiddle to illustrate this better:

http://jsfiddle.net/vengiss/3W5qe/

I'm using jQuery and the Malsup's Ajax Form plugin but I believe this behavior is independent of the plugin, I just need to `return false` to the `beforeSubmit` function depending on the `POST` request so the form doesn't get submitted every time. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Comment: FYI, if you put your code inside the `ready` handler, it already gets `jQuery` passed as first argument, so you can simply remove the immediate function call: `jQuery(function($) { ... code here ...});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible to do when dealing with async functions.  The function which calls `post` will return immediately while the ajax call back will return at some point in the future.  It's not possible to return a future result from the present.

Instead what you need to do is pass a callback to the original function.  This function will eventually be called with the result of the ajax call

```
var makePostCall = function(callback) {
  $.post('/echo/json/', { json: jsonStuff }, function(resp) {
    if (resp.stuff !== $('#test').val()) { 
      // Cancel form submittion
      alert('Need to type "test"');
      callback(false);
    } else { 
      callback(true);
    }}, 'json');
};
```

Then switch the code which expected a prompt response from `makePostCall` to using a callback instead.

```
// Synchronous version 
if (makePostCall()) { 
  // True code 
} else {
  // false code
}

// Async version
makePostCall(function (result) {
  if (result) {
    // True code
  } else {
    // False code
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put async:false parameter to ajax request then you can control future responce and send back the result to parent.  see following main lines enclosed within ***
       add: function (e, data) {

```
    //before upload file check server has that file already uploaded
      ***var flag=false;***
      $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'json',
                url:"xyz.jsp",
                ***async:false,***
                data:{  
                         filename : upload_filename,
                         docname : upload_docname,
                         userid : upload_userid,
                    },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    ***flag=true;***
                },
                error:function(request,errorType,errorMessage) 
                {
                    alert ('error - '+errorType+'with message - '+errorMessage);
                }
        });

       ***return flag;***

        }
```